# Pantalla de cargar, mientras se suben ficheros

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Buenas tengo un formulario para subir imagenes al servidor y las inserto en una bd y las subo a una carpeta del servidor. Pero no se como hacer para mostrar "algo" mientras las imagenes se están cargando.

Este es el AJAX con el que subo las fotos:

```
$(function(){
            $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var f = $(this);
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
                formData.append("dato", "valor");
                //formData.append(f.attr("name"), $(this)[0].files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/add-galeria.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                })
                    .done(function(res){
                        $("#mensaje").html(res);
                        toastr["success"]("Fotos subidas", "Mensaje")
                        setTimeout(function () {
                               window.location.href = "venta-vivienda.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                           }, 1500); //will call the function after 2 secs
                    });
            });
        });
```

Este el php add-galeria.php

```
include "../../conexion/conecta.php";
  $id =$_POST['id'];

    //Como el elemento es un arreglos utilizamos foreach para extraer todos los valores
    foreach($_FILES["archivo"]['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        //Validamos que el archivo exista
        if($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]) {
            $filename = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$key]; //Obtenemos el nombre original del archivo
            $source = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$key]; //Obtenemos un nombre temporal del archivo

            $directorio = '../../images/galeria/'; //Declaramos un  variable con la ruta donde guardaremos los archivos

            //Validamos si la ruta de destino existe, en caso de no existir la creamos
            if(!file_exists($directorio)){
                mkdir($directorio, 0777) or die("No se puede crear el directorio de extracci&oacute;n");
            }

            $dir=opendir($directorio); //Abrimos el directorio de destino
            $target_path = $directorio.'/'.$filename; //Indicamos la ruta de destino, así como el nombre del archivo

            //Movemos y validamos que el archivo se haya cargado correctamente
            //El primer campo es el origen y el segundo el destino
            if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
                sleep(3);//retrasamos la petición 3 segundos
                } else {
                echo "";
            }
      $results = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Foto (idVivienda, ruta ) VALUES ($id, '$filename')");
            //closedir($dir); //Cerramos el directorio de destino
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las funciones `beforeSend y complete` para mostrar un [Spinner](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/spinners/). Te recomiendo le eches un vistazo a la documentación de [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo puedes utilizar las funciones.

Sólo aclaro, estas utlizando mal la función `done`, esta está pensada para cuando el servidor termine de hacer su trabajo, independiente si falló o no, esta se invocará, imagina que tu servidor tiene un error de programación y retorna un error 500 que es un error interno, la función `done` se lanzará pero no creo que quieras que se lance después que falló. En cambio existe `success`, esta solo se invoca si te retorna un 200 el servidor.

```js
$( () => {

  $.ajax({
     
     url: 'url',
     method: 'post',
     data: data,
     
     beforeSend: () => {
      //Esta función se invocará cuando inicie la carga de archivos, aqui puedes poner por ejemplo que se muestre un loader
      $('.loader').show('fast');
     },
     
     complete: () => {
      //Esta función se invoca cuando el servidor retorna un estado (por ejemplo un 200, 404, 500 etc), aquí apagas el loader
      $('.loader').hide('slow');
     },
     
     success: (result) => {
      //Si el resultado es un status 200, entonces todo se hizo bien, aquí haces tu lógica
     }
    
  });

});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funciono y cambie la función done gracias!!